# code to find the value of nCr shows the answer to some values as 0( Ex:30 15)

Tags: c++

The following is the code:
#include 
using namespace std;

```
int factorial(int num){       
unsigned long long int fact=1;
for (int i = num; i >=1; i--)
{
    fact=fact*i;
}
return fact;
}

int main()
{
unsigned long long int n,r,value;
cout<<"Enter a number whose nCr value is to be calculated (n and r respectively): ";
cin>>n>>r;
 unsigned long long int a=factorial(n);
 unsigned long long int b=factorial(r);
 unsigned long long int c=factorial(n-r);
 value=a/(b*c);
 cout<<"The value of nCr is : "<<value;
 return 0;
}
```

Why do I get the answer to some of the inputs like (30 15),(30 12), etc as 0.

Comment: Try to calculate what these are. You're likely to discover that there aren't enough atoms in the universe to represent these numbers, much less than just an `unsigned long long`. Your are not going to learn anything about C++ from these kinds of useless coding puzzles, from spam sites that claim that all you need to become a C++ uberhacker is to do these puzzles. This is not true.

Comment: Your `factorial` function is declared to return `int`, so why are you storing its return value in `unsigned long long int`s when you call it?

Answer (score 2):

30! is a very large 33-digit number, so that's overflowing the int variable your program is trying to store it in. If you print it out, you'll see the actual value that gets stored in `a` is smaller than the value of `b*c` in the denominator of the final computation, so `value=a/(b*c);` gets truncated to 0 by integer division.

Even if you return the result of `factorial` as an `unsigned long long int` the result of 30! will overflow, since it can only store 64 bits (and that's compiler dependent).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

unsigned long long int factorial(int num) {
    unsigned long long int fact = 1;
    for (int i = num; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        fact = fact * i;
    }
    return fact;
}


int main()
{
    unsigned long long int n, r, value;
    std::cout << "Enter a number whose nCr value is to be calculated (n and r respectively): ";
    std::cin >> n >> r;
    unsigned long long int a = factorial(n);
    std::cout << "n! = " << a << std::endl;
    unsigned long long int b = factorial(r);
    std::cout << "r! = " << b << std::endl;
    unsigned long long int c = factorial(n - r);
    std::cout << "(n-r)! = " << c << std::endl;
    std::cout << "r!(n-r)! = " << b*c << std::endl;
    value = a / (b*c);
    std::cout << "The value of nCr is : " << value << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a number whose nCr value is to be calculated (n and r respectively): 30 12
n! = 9682165104862298112
r! = 479001600
(n-r)! = 6402373705728000
r!(n-r)! = 12940075575627743232
The value of nCr is : 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with your code is return type of factorial Method it should be same as the return type of "fact".

Second issue with code is that it cannot handle huge number above i.e, max value of unsigned long long int "18,446,744,073,709,551,615"(https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_types.htm).
So just change the data types of variables fact,a,b,c and factorial method to "long double" which can accomodate 12 bytes of data.

Code below is just modified for tracing purpose... you can skip the line which you don't need. Be careful with data types. Code is modified as per your requirement for huge calculations.
Please reply if you have any confusion. And up-vote my answer if it looks right to you.

You can remove std:: from the code if not need by your compiler.

```
    #include <iostream>
    long double factorial(int num){       
    long double fact=1;
    for (int i = num; i >=1; i--)
    {
      fact=fact*i;
    }
     return fact;
    }

    int main()
    {
     unsigned long long int n=0,r=0;
     long double value=0;
     std::cout<<"Enter a number whose nCr value is to be calculated (n and r respectively): ";
     std::cin>>n>>r;
     std::cout<<n;
     std::cout<<r;
     long double a=factorial(n);
     long double b=factorial(r);
     long double c=factorial(n-r);
     std::cout<<"\na="<<a;
     std::cout<<"\nb="<<b;
     std::cout<<"\nc="<<c;
     long double d = b*c;
     std::cout<<"\nd="<<d;
     value=(unsigned long long int)(a/d);
     std::cout<<"\nThe value of nCr is : "<<value;
     return 0;
    `enter code here`}
```

Comment: *max value of unsigned long long int "18,446,744,073,709,551,615"* currently and practically, yes, but [the C++ Standard does not specify the upper limits of integer types other than to say that an integer type can't be larger than the next largest integer type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Properties). Currently there is no type larger than `long long`, so its maximum size is restricted only by the implementation. If the compiler writers decide to make any or all of the integer types  (`char` through `long long`) 128 bits, that's their call.

Comment: At least one major historical computer manufacturer, Cray, did almost exactly this. `long long` didn't exist yet and everything was 32 bit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.... I assumed that code in actual question is not giving appropriate result to him, that means his version of c++ implementation doesn't support those many bytes. Hence modified this code to support his compiler and other generic compilers.